When is 2024 Counterspell more likely to succeed than 2014 Counterspell?
I'm trying to evaluate the consequences of 5e's 2024 PHB changing Counterspell from a spellcasting ability check by the caster against a DC based on the spell level to a Constutution save by the target against the caster's spell save DC. (Note: here I refer to the caster and target of Counterspell, not the spell being countered.) The basic question I'm trying to answer is: which version of Counterspell is more likely to successfully counter a spell? A quick analysis reveals that the answer must depend on:

The level of the spell being countered, since this affects the DC for the check but not the save DC.
The caster's proficiency bonus, since this is added to their spell save DC but not their spellcasting ability check.
The target's CON save modifier

I believe the answer does not depend on the caster's spellcasting ability modifier, since that is added to both the check and the save DC. Given all this, is there an easy rule I can apply to figure out which version of Counterspell has the higher chance of success?
For the purposes of this question:

Assume that the spell being countered is of a higher level than Counterspell, because otherwise 2014 Counterspell is trivially superior with a 100% chance of success.
Ignore any other differences between the spells, such as the slightly different effects on success and slightly different reaction triggers.
Ignore any external factors that might change the outcome of the check/save such as Legendary Resistance, effects that grant advantage or disadvantage, or effects that add additional modifiers.

In other words, I only care about comparing the relative probability of a successfully countering a spell with each version of Counterspell, in the case where both versions require a roll.

I think you try to compare a probability dependent on a CON save to a probability depending on spellcasting ability - spell level. It is like a comparison of apple to orange.

Btw, the idea that spellcasting success depend on con modifiers, that remembers me to d&d4. My first instinctual idea would be to just use the 2014 version as dm rule.

@GraySheep Both versions of Counterspell have a probability of success that can be compared against each other. I don't think it's apples to oranges.

Yes, I admit you can actually calculate a probability of that one of them is bigger.

Let:
$$
\begin{align}
R &:\text{the die roll}\\
s_c &:\text{the caster’s spellcasting ability bonus}\\
p_c &:\text{the caster’s proficiency bonus}\\
l &:\text{the spell level}\\
c_t &:\text{the target’s constitution ability bonus}\\
p_t &:\text{the target’s proficiency bonus}\\
Pr(...) &: \text{the probability that the condition in the brackets is satisfied}\\
\end{align}
$$
The relevant 2014 inequality is:
$$
\begin{align} 
R+s_c&\ge 10+l\\
R &\ge 10+l-s_c\\
\end{align} 
$$
And:
$$
\begin{align}
Pr(R \ge 10+l-s_c) &= {{21-(10+l-s_c)}\over 20}^{1,2}\\
&= {{11-l+s_c}\over 20}\\
\end{align}
$$
The relevant 2024 inequality is:
$$
\begin{align} 
R+c_t+p_t&\le 8+s_c+p_c\\
R&\le 8+s_c+p_c-c_t-p_t\\
\end{align} 
$$
And:
$$
\begin{align}
Pr(R\le 8+s_c+p_c-c_t-p_t) &= {{8+s_c+p_c-c_t-p_t-1}\over 20}^{1,3}\\
&= {{7+s_c+p_c-c_t-p_t}\over 20}\\
\end{align} 
$$
So, the 2024 is strictly better when:
$$
\begin{align} 
{{7+s_c+p_c-c_t-p_t}\over 20} &> {{11-l+s_c}\over 20}\\
p_c+l &> 4+c_t+p_t\\
\end{align} 
$$
Just eyeballing:

you are correct that the spellcasting modifier doesn't affect the outcome.
the 2014 version is always better for spell levels 1-3 (\$l\le3\$ ) because it works automatically.
proficiency bonuses range from +2 to +9, but PCs are capped at +6. If engaged with enemies of the same CR as their level, these bonuses will cancel out if the target is proficient in Constitution saving throws; most PC-like casters don't, but monsters are quite variable.
Constitution modifiers range from -5 to +10, but PCs are usually capped at +5. It is unusual to encounter an enemy with a negative constitution modifier.


\$^1\$ This is only true when the right-hand side of the inequality is between 1 and 20 inclusive. There are combinations of the variables that are possible in the game where this is not true. However, such circumstances would be so unusual at the table (e.g., a person with a negative spellcasting modifier trying to counterspell a high-level spell) that they can safely be ignored.
\$^2\$ This formula comes from noting that the right-hand side represents the target number that the roll must equal or exceed. Taking this number from 21 gives the number of sides on a d20 that are that number or greater.
\$^3\$ This formula comes from noting that the right-hand side represents the target number that the roll must be less than. Taking 1 from this number gives the number of sides on a d20 that are that number or greater.

Hi Dale, in your final comments when you say "it" will usually be worse, which one are you talking about? Sorry, it might be me but I lost track of the antecedent. :D Could you specify it please?

Ok, so if we assume the proficiency bonuses are equal and cancel out, we have l > 4 + c_t, which means 2024 CS generally only outperforms 2014 CS against high level spells. On the other hand, if the target isn't proficient in CON saves, then we have l > 4 + c_t - p_c, and 2024 CS comes out looking pretty good even against 4th level spells, and only gets better from there.

I wonder if "Heightened Spell" Meta magic can be used as a part of counterspell, since that's a reaction.  This provides disadvantage on a saving throw.  Probably worth its own question.

This answer means nothing I am afraid. Might as well write in French.

@SeriousBri What is unclear about the answer? The final inequality can't be simplified any further unless you assume specific values for the variables.

@RyanC.Thompson a well written version of this answer would probably have all the working out in spoiler quotes for those who care, and have the final answer written in either words, or better yet shown with a table. Most people leave variables at school and really don't want to deal with them again.

As far as I can see, in the MM there are a total of 60 spellcasters, The average Con Save bonus is +4, +/- 3.5 StdDev. (17 of them are proficient, mostly Githyanki, greater Undead, and Outsiders, and for that subgroup, the average Save bonus is +8 +/-3 StdDev; the complement of 43 that are not proficient are NPC casters and sylvan setting casters, but again includes geater Undead and Outsiders;  their save on aveage is +3 +/- 2.5 StdDev).

Generally for level 4+ spells you do better, but you are often worse off when it counts
To build on @Dale's answer, which gives you the mathematical formula, you fare better when

player proficiency bonus + level of spell to counter > 4 + monster Con save bonus

here are some more practical observations:

Looking at the formula, when you get Counterspell in tier 2, when your proficiency bonus is +3, nearly canceling out the 4 on the other side of the equation, so initially this simplifies to: you are better off, if the spell level is one greater than the monster's Con Save bonus. As the old version automatically won for spells of level 1-3, that means the relevant spell levels here are level 4 and up, and you are better off if that plus one beats the monster's Con Save bonus, which means the monster needs to have a Con save bonus smaller than +5. (Later on in your career, as your PB increases to +4, +5 and +6, the monsters will have to have a Con save bonus of +6 or +7 or +8 or they will be worse off).

There are a total of 60 different monsters in the Monster Manual (2014 edition) with a Spellcasting or Innate Spellcasting feature. Of course, in addition you have many more Monsters from expansions, but looking at those can give you some base ideas. Overall, their average Con Saving Throw bonus is +4, which means that against a randomly selected spellcaster, you can expect to be better off countering their level 4+ spell.

There are only 21 that have a bonus better than +5 and which initially will fare better — most of them because they are proficient in Con saves (except some genies, the Death Knight, Empyrean and Solar who just do it with high Con), only 16 have +6 or better, and only 13  have +7 or better. That means that for about 65% of all spellcasting kinds of monsters you could face, you will be better off when countering a level 4 spell or higher.


On the other end of the spectrum, you are losing some. Let's look at some high profile examples. The monsters with the highest Con save bonus are the Pit Fiend (+13), Planetar (+12), Androsphinx (+11), Cloud/Storm Giant, Empyrean and Lich (all +10). Most of them, however, are not able to cast 9th level spells.

The Pit Fiend at best manages a hold monster  for a max total of 6+5=11 on your side of the equation, vs. 4+13=17 on his, so you are much worse off against him.
The Planetar is an unlikely opponent, an in the even more unlikely event that you need to counter his control weather, your 6+8=14 will put you worse vs his 4+12=16.
The Androsphinx's highest level spells are 6th, giving you 6+6=12 vs their 4+11=15, no dice.
The Lich is a much more likely endgame opponent. The have a 9th level slot, so when they cast their 9th level power word kill on you, your 6+9=15 will just so beat their 4+10=14, and you have better chances of surviving that.
The cloud or storm giant only can cast control weather, level 8, so 14 vs 14 leaves you slightly worse there. The same goes for the Empyrean's earthquake.

HOWEVER, many of these higher level monsters with access to 8th or 9th level spells also do have legendary resistance.

Legendary Resistance (3/Day). If the lich fails a saving throw, it can choose to succeed instead.

So in real terms, the new counterspell sucks big time against them, because it just does not work at all. That lich will cast power word kill on your wizard, your wizard will counter forcing it to make a Con save, and if its own counterspell does not work on yours, it can just opt to kill you anyways.
The same goes for the Empyrean, and the Pit Fiend has

Magic Resistance. The pit fiend has advantage on saving
throws against spells and other magical effects.

so it will save with advantage to resist your Counterspell.
The NPCs Mage and Archmage are also often used in published modules. For them you are looking pretty OK:

The Mage can cast 5th level spells, Con save bonus +0. You probably encounter him around when your have PB +4, but looking at your best case, it is 6+5=11 vs 4+0, so better for you.

The Archmage has one 9th level spell, and a measly Con Save of 1, so with 6+9=15 vs 4+1=5, the odds are heavily in your favor. He also has magic resistance, but the difference here is so great, you still likely win out.



P.S. With all that said, and I know it is not part of the question, so just as a side comment on why I think this change is a nerf to Counterspell (which may be fine, it was a super powerful spell):
Not only will you do worse against opponents with magic resistance or legendary resistance, but also will you lose the inevitability of upcasting. Sure it is more costly to counter the enemy Mage's spell with one of your level 5 slots, but in exchange, unless your counter gets countered (and a Mage who cast cone of cold on you couldn't as they only have one level 5), you are sure that you will stop the effect. That certainty is worth a lot. You lose that with the new version. You of course also lose the little fun mini-game of second guessing if they will lead with their most powerful spell, if they know they face another wizard.
The main benefit for the players is that they do not lose their spell slot any more when they get countered, probably because that felt like adding insult to injury, while monster and NPC spellcasters, once they all migrate to the new Spellcasting template, will lose theirs.
